# Piecewise imposes internal boundaries in NDSolve - is this expected?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, piecewise

In the following code I used `True` as the predicate for `DirichletCondition` and found that the boundary condition was applied not only at the boundary of the specified region but also at the internal boundary implied by the `Piecewise` potential.

```
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{-1, x^2 + y^2 < 0.25}}, 0]

sol = NDSolveValue[{
    Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == f[x, y],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]
    }, u, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]];

Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[], PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

I can confirm that there is an internal boundary by looking at the boundary of the FEM mesh:

```
NDSolve`FEM`ToBoundaryMesh[sol["ElementMesh"]]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

The result I wanted can be obtained by explicitly giving just the outer boundary to `DirichletCondition`:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{
    Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == f[x, y],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, {x, y} ∈ Circle[]]
    }, u, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]];

Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[], PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

My question is whether the behaviour using `True` is correct, i.e. expected and documented? My expectation was that the only the boundary of the explicitly given `Disk[]` region would be used (though I can understand *why* the internal FEM code creates the internal boundary).

Comment: Strangely, `f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{-1, 0 <= x^2 + y^2 < 0.25}}, 0]` solves the problem!

Comment: @bbgodfrey, yes, it solves the problem but is less accurate. Simon's suggestion is the way to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let us look at what happens a bit and start with your first question (title):

"Piecewise imposes internal boundaries in NDSolve - is this expected"

Yes, that is expected if the function introduces a discontinuity in one of the coefficients and the spatial discretization method is the finite element method (FEM). The FEM will produce better results if the elements do not cross the discontinuity. `NDSolve` FEM functionality has to assume that the customer using `NDSolve` does not know anything about the FEM in fact she/he should not need to know that `NDSolve` uses the FEM. Having an *automatic* feature detection is a major advantage of using `NDSolve` and this type of functionality will certainly be extended upon.

That functionality like this exists is documented in the section [Partial Differential Equations with Variable Coefficients](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html).

One can switch that feature detection off by hiding the internal of the `Piecewise` behind a `?NumericQ`. I'd advise against this. This will return a result that is less accurate then with the discontinuity detection on.

Now, from the details section of the documentation of [`DirichletCondition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletCondition.html?q=DirichletCondition)

"Dirichlet conditions are enforced at each point in the discretization of [PartialD][CapitalOmega] where pred is True."

What does this mean? During the conversion of the region what ever is on the boundary is considered for deploying the Dirichlet condition if `True` is requested. And here is the crux: On one hand the FEM gives better results with the discontinuity represented in the mesh and that has as a consequence that the discontinuity line is also part of the boundary - it is two different materials you are considering they do have boundaries also in nature.

I most certainly understand that you did not expect this. But you also expect the best possible result; so we have a conflict of interests so to speak. I am not sure how this can be resolved. A few things that could be considered: Add an example to the possible issues section of the documentation of `DirichletCondition`. Add a warning message that `True` might not be be what you'd expect. Let me know what you think.

So, I understand it's not expected but I would not go as far as saying it's a bug. You already put forward a good way to deal with this by giving an explicit predicate:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{
    Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == f[x, y],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, {x, y} ∈ Circle[]]
    }, u, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]];

Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[], PlotPoints -> 50]
```

Here is another example that (in Version 10.3) does not work out of the box but should and illustrates that automatic feature detection is indeed wanted:

```
NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x == 0 && y == 0]}, u, {x, 
   y} \[Element] Disk[]]

NDSolveValue::bcnop: "No places were found on the boundary where x==0&&y==0 was True, so DirichletCondition[u==1,x==0&&y==0] will effectively be ignored"
```

Because the automatic feature detection does not (yet) work for boundary conditions a message is given that the predicate of the Dirichlet condition inside the region can not be satisfied. Now, helping `NDSolve` a bit with:

```
if = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 1, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x == 0 && y == 0]}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"IncludePoints" -> {{0, 0}}}}]
```

Will generate an interpolating function with the expected property:

```
if[0, 0]
1.0
```

If we look at the `PointElements` in the mesh we see that now the center coordinate *is* part of the mesh:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ToBoundaryMesh[if["ElementMesh"]][
 "Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements"]]
```

[image]

And a plot looks reasonable:

```
Plot3D[if[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] if["ElementMesh"], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

This should have worked without the need to specify the additional point manually but `NDSolve` should have included it automatically. The point I like to make is that one does want NDSolve to make changes to the discretized region.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation and link to the tutorial. I agree that automatic discontinuity detection is desirable - and I will probably just always specify the boundary explicitly in future. IMO it would be sufficient to add a "possible issue" to the documentation as you suggest.

Answer (score 8):

As I noted in a comment, redefining `f` in a way that does not change its value,

```
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{-1, 0 <= x^2 + y^2 < 0.25}}, 0]
```

yields the desired solution, shown in the second plot in the question.  The corresponding `Wiremesh` does not exhibit an internal boundary.

**Addendum**

In fact, all but one of the definitions I tried give the right answer:

```
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{-1, (x^2 + y^2 <= 0.25) && (x | y) ∈ Reals}}, 0]

f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{-1, Abs[x^2 + y^2] < 0.25}}, 0]

f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{-1, x^2 + y^2 < 0.25 && -1 <= x && -1 <= y}}, 0]

f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{-1, -10^10 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 0.25}}, 0]
```

One does not, however.

```
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{-1, -Infinity < x^2 + y^2 <= 0.25}}, 0]
sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == f[x, y],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]];
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[], PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]
```

Although the shape seems correct, the peak value, `sol[0, 0] = 0.106813`, is too small by nearly 1/3.

[image]

Very strange!

Comment: The `-Infinity` one is a bug since that only includes part of the discontinuity. `NDSolve`FEM`ToBoundaryMesh[sol["ElementMesh"]]["Wireframe"]` If you turn the graphics you will see the defect.

Answer (score 4):

Version 10.3.0:

If you just deny Mathematica's access to the interior of `f`, you get the expected result:

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_] := Piecewise[{{-1, x^2 + y^2 < 0.25}}, 0]

sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == f[x, y], 
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]];

Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

So, for me it's a bug. And even more since, when blocking access to bbgodfrey definition with the `-Infinity`, I also get the right answer:

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_] := Piecewise[{{-1, -Infinity < x^2 + y^2 <= 0.25}}, 0]
```

---

I recently also had a case where blocking access to the interior of the function also solved the problem:

```
function3[t_] := If[t < 5, 5, 
  Interpolation[{{5, 5}, {10, 10}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1][t]]

NDSolveValue[{total[0] == 0, total'[t] == function3[t]}, total, {t, 0, 10}][10]
(*62.5*)
```

> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>

Right answer, but, in my opinion, the warning message shouldn't be there

By denying the access, with `_?NumericQ`, the warning goes away.

Wolfram Research support answered:

> It is an expected behavior for numerical methods of finding solutions to differential equations to iterate in a vicinity of each point, e.g.  0 /-[Epsilon] or 5 /-[Epsilon] where [Epsilon] is a small positive real number. In order to avoid receiving the warning messages, one has to extend the definition of the functions to accommodate for /-[Epsilon] or limit the definition of the function to only evaluate for numerical values.

Which I get it, at the same time I don't...

Comment: The second issue you mention is not related to the discussion here; it's a different matter. I filed this as a suggestion for improvement.

Comment: As a side note: you can use `total[10]` as the dependent variable `NDSolveValue[{total[0]==0,total'[t]==function3[t]},  total[10], {t, 0, 10}]` that will evaluate at `t==10`

Comment: @user21 I kind of knew that it was a different matter, but I grabbed the opportunity to have it analysed by the same "population"... :-) But I'll have to read your answer on the OP question, more carefully, to understand the full depth of this advantage detail.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of NDSolve described in the question concerns only the versions of Mathematica ealier than 11.1

Compare

Mathematica 11.1 :
[image]

Mathematica 11.2 :

[image]

This information was discovered [in the Wolfram Technology Cofrerence 2017, Paritosh Mokhasi's presentation on Finite Elements](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=104&disp=list&p=4&v=2030)  , time=7:02 (or 5:25, I don't get reproducbile timing !). The slider title is : "Dirichlet conditions : Multiple materials"

Comment: The fact that you do not get the same result in V11.2 is a bug in V11.2 that is fixed in the next version. So V11.3 (or what ever it's name will be) will show the same result as V11.1

Comment: Strange. My first impression is that it is contraditory with what I have understood from Paritosh Mokhasi's presentation. I will investigate this, but not now.