# Solution of Poisson equation with two regions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm trying to figure out how is possible to solve a Poisson equation

$\nabla\cdot[d(x,y)\nabla u]+1=0$

where $d(x,y)$ equals 1 in one region and 2 in another one. Let say I have homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions.

The two regions should be physically distinct, I mean do not use just

```
d[x_,y_]:=If[x<0.5,1,2]
```

if x=0.5 is the edge between the two regions.

Thanks for the suggestion(s)
F

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried the "If" solution, and also merging two regions. In the last case there is no internal boundary, further I do not know how to address $d(x,y)$ for the two regions.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, could you not solve the equation once per region with the appropriate coefficient - maybe you could clarify what you mean by "distinct" - a code example would be best.

Comment: Can this be a case for "matched asymptotics" (perturbation methods)?.. or am I over-complicating the problem?

Comment: No, the problem I've illustrated implies that across the interface of the two domains both the function $u$ and the normal flux $d\nabla u\cdot n$ must be continuous.  Setting a system of PDE by requiring these constraints would be ok, too. But how to do that? If I had the code I've solved the problem.

Comment: @DrN: yes you do! :)

Comment: I've found something in here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#509267359

Comment: @user21 I think this is related to [your answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98759/862). In Fabio's case the automatic feature detection seems to fail and no internal boundary is created by `NDSolve`. His solution is to use ``NDSolve`FEM`` directly to gain better control over the mesh, which I guess is what you'd recommend?

Comment: @SimonWoods, well observed. If one changes the region to `{x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]` then the automatic feature detection works. With time more and more regions and triggers should work.

Answer (score 4):

I've found

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
bndmesh = 
  ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.5, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 
      1}},
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        1}, {2, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 3}, {3, 2}}]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bndmesh];
d = If[x <= 0.5, 1, 10];
usol = NDSolve[{Div[d Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 1 == 0, 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, 
      x == 0 || x == 1 || y == 0 || y == 1]}, 
    u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh][[1]];
{bndmesh["Wireframe"], mesh["Wireframe"], 
 Plot3D[u[x, y] /. usol, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]}
```

[image]

as a possible solution.

Any enhancement/advice to that?